Delta of ATM barrier option
Can you please share the intuition behind the delta of a ATM down & in PUT being less than a ATM plain vanilla put (usually around 0.3 instead of 0.5)?

Say you are very close to expiry, and the barrier is below the strike of the option - if you are atmf, for a small drop in price, the put price won't change much as it needs to also be below the barrier, to give its holder any value at expiry. Therefore, the delta is a lot smaller than a vanilla put whose intrinsic value grows one for one with the underlying below the strike at expiry.

Because the probability of it expiring in the money is less than that of a vanilla since the barrier still needs to be touched.

Best case, upon down move, the barrier is sure to be broken and so the new price is the put price. Old price is less than a put price. So it's not obvious that it is lesser.
It will be true if movement in probability of barrier broken is small enough, which is probably what we say will happen, but it is not obvious the other explanations take this in account.
A good explanation should be sensitive to when results overturn
